# Rank of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ over $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

I was reading a book and, at some point, the author states that, for $A$ torsion-free abelian group (i.e $\Bbb{Z}$-module), the ranks of $\Bbb{Q}\otimes A$ and $A$ are the same.

I was able to prove this fact using $rank(\Bbb{Q}\otimes A)=rank(\Bbb{Q})rank(A)$ and $rank(\Bbb{Q})=1$, where the rank is, by definition, the cardinality of a maximal $\Bbb{Z}$-linearly independent system of a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

More generally, I know that $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subgroup (i.e. $\Bbb{Z}$-submodule) of the group $\Bbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.
So my questions are:

> (1) what's the rank of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ over $\Bbb{Z}$?
>
> (2) and what is the rank of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$?

Heuristics suggests to me that they are both $1$, but I failed to prove that.

The definition I know is the following:
a $p$-adic number is an element of the form $x=p^{-m}\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i$, while a $p$-adic integers has the form $y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i$, where $m\in\Bbb{Z}$, $a_i\in \{0,\dots,p-1\}$.
They main problem I have is that I don't know how to deal with "tails" like $\sum_{i=N}^\infty a_ip^i$ for some $N>0$.

May you help me, please?

Comment: The rank of $\mathbb Q_p$ over $\mathbb Z_p$ is $1$.  More generally if $R$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$, then $K$ has rank one over $R$.  I expect that the rank of $\mathbb Q_p$ over $\mathbb Z$ is infinite.

Comment: @D_S Can you suggest a reference where I can find some proof (or can you prove it directly)? What I have written concerns abelian group theory.